# Using Protocol Buffer to Serialize Bytes Python3

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, type-conversion, encryption-symmetric, protocol-buffers

I am trying to serialize a bytes object - which is an initialization vector for my program's encryption. But, the Google Protocol Buffer only accepts strings. It seems like the error starts with casting bytes to string. Am I using the correct method to do this? Thank you for any help or guidance!

Or also, can I make the Initialization Vector a string object for AES-CBC mode encryption?

**Code**

- Cast the bytes to a string

  - `string_iv = str(bytes_iv, 'utf-8')`
- Serialize the string using SerializeToString():

  - `serialized_iv = IV.SerializeToString()`
- Use ParseToString() to recover the string:

  - `IV.ParseFromString( serialized_iv )`
- And finally, UTF-8 encode the string back to bytes:

  - `bytes_iv = bytes(IV.string_iv, encoding= 'utf-8')`

**Error**

string_iv = str(bytes_iv, 'utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 3: invalid start byte

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* cast an arbitrary `bytes` object to `str`, these are your option:

- simply call `str()` on the object. It will turn it into `repr` form, ie. something that could be parsed as a `bytes` literal, eg. `"b'abc\x00\xffabc'"`
- decode with "latin1". This will always work, even though it technically makes no sense if the data isn't text encoded with Latin-1.
- use base64 or base85 encoding (the standard library has a `base64` module wich covers both)